# How to convert non-formats to JSON with Find/Replace?

Tags: regex, json, replace

How can I use Find & Replace (or Regex or Vim or whatever) to convert the following bunch:

```
1
string one
2
string two
3
stirng three
4
string four
.
.
.
```

to a JSON format, like so:

```
1: { 1: 'string one' },
2: { 1: 'string two' },
3: { 1: 'string three' },
4: { 1: 'string four' }
.
.
.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a valid JSON format, for one thing JSON keys have to be strings.

Answer (score 1):

Using vim:
1-) I would record a macro to put key and content in the same line (couldn't find how to apply regex to multiple lines)
2-)%s/\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\1: {'\1':\'\2'},/g 
The first part (0-9)+ will get the index, the second part (.*) will get the rest of the string.

Then you can pretty much what you want with it.
In this example, I'm following your syntax

key: {'key':'value'},

In this case, you will have a comma in the last line, but it should not be a problem.

Comment: Nice! Though I get the following: 
1: {'1':'s'},tring one
2: {'2':'s'},tring two
3: {'3':'s'},tirng three
4: {'4':'s'},tring four

Comment: There is a missing * in the second part. Should be \\(.\*\\). The complete line is: %s/\\([0-9]\\+\\) \\(.\*\\)/\\1: {'\1':\'\2'},/g . Sorry about that